# resize image 950*950 in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I hesitated on posting this question cause I saw dozens of them here, but all the answers didn't work.

So, I have this working code. It uploads picture and getting  thumbnails.

I allow users to upload a 950*950 pictures. I want to resize those pics to fit in my show page.

So, here is part of the resize:

```
    $id=uniqid();

            $folder = $this->getDir($id);

            $dir=FCPATH.'upload/biz_photos/'.$folder.'/';

            if(!is_dir($dir)) {

              mkdirs($dir);
    }

    //handle img
    $des_file=$dir.$id.'.jpg';

            $thumb_file=$dir.$id.'.thumb.jpg';

            $info=getimagesize($org_file);

            if($info[0] <= 300) {

            copy($org_file,$dir.$id.'.jpg');

            }

            else

            {

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';

    $config['source_image']=$org_file;

    $config['new_image'] = $des_file;

        $config['overwrite']= true;

            $config['maintain_ratio'] =true;

            $config['width'] = 600;

            $config['height'] = floor(($info[1]/$info[0])*600);

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        $this->image_lib->resize();

            // handle if there is any problem

            if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){

              echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();

            }

    }
```

Like when I test it, and upload a 950*950, and then check the uploaded image, the size still 
the original one. No resizing

Comment: Is the file specified by `$des_file` being created/overwritten when you run this?

Comment: Also a few notes: The image library doesn't use an overwrite preference (you might have it confused with the file upload library). You are running the resize() function twice (first just after the initialize() and again in the if statement). You can remove the first one.

Comment: @Samutz Yeah, I am getting the image uploaded, no problem. I am confused about what you said about the image library doesn't use an overwrite preference.

Comment: `$config['overwrite'] = true;` doesn't do anything for the image library. As far as it not resizing, the only thing I can think of is possibly a problem with GD2. I tried to reproduce the problem on my test site with the same config, but it worked fine.

Comment: But wouldn't thumbnails and watermarking work if it a GD problem?

Comment: They probably wouldn't work. You didn't show any thumbnail or watermarking code in the question, so I didn't know you were doing either. If you're saying they do work, then you should double check permissions and make sure `$des_file` is being written and you're not just seeing an older version of the file.

Comment: Thumbnails and watermarking work fine. The destination folder is set to 777. The way I am testing is, upload the image and check if it's uploaded right otherwise delete the file. I tried other pictures, but it just seems nothing working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the problem after few hours. So, I have a thumbnail function and I was passing to it the original picture instead of passing it the new picture (the sized picture).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This image resize class is easy to set up and use 
https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize

Comment: Nice class by the way, but I am trying to keep it CI way

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['source_image']=$org_file;
$config['new_image'] = $des_file;
$config['overwrite']= true;
$config['maintain_ratio'] =true;
$config['width'] = 950;
$config['height'] = 950;
$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```