# Resize image while keeping the image content in thumbnail

Tags: php, codeigniter, resize

Is there a way to resize an image, so it keeps the full content of the image.
All the solution I've tried it going from the middle of the picture and out, so the top, right, bottom and left of the picture is cut out.

Is there a solution where I can zoom out the picture - hope it make sense

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't keep the whole image if I want the image to be resized to a fixed size (300x300 for instance)

Comment: if your image is like 1650px900px, you'll have to resize first to 550px x 300 px and then crop to 300 x 300

Comment: There are other questions out there on this...no? Here's one for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210781/resize-image-950950-in-codeigniter/22211885#22211885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the images aspect ratio when scaling it (changing its size). There is a pretty simple equation for doing this:

```
newWidth / oldWidth = ratio
oldHeight * ratio = newHeight
```

or vice versa with the height.

Hope this helps.